# Fit Inverse Gamma Distribution to dataset in R

Tags: r, distributions, fitting, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am having some problems in modifying Procrastinator's code that assesses the fit of the Inverse Gamma distribution to some randomly generated data. I am refering to the code appearing in the following link:

['Fixing' PearsonFitML to fit to a Pearson V distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33616/fixing-pearsonfitml-to-fit-to-a-pearson-v-distribution)

In my case, I have the dataset save in a .csv file which I directly import in R for further processing. MY modification of this code is as follows:

```
# Required packages
library(MCMCpack)

data=my.csv.data$V1
hist(data)

# log-likelihood
ll = function(par){
if(par[1]>0 & par[2]>0 & par[3]<min(data)) return( -sum(log(dinvgamma(data-    par[3],par[1],par[2]))) )
else return(Inf)
}

# MLE
mle = optim(c(5,2,2),ll)
params = mle$par

# Fit
hist(data,probability=T,ylim=c(0,2.5))
points(seq(2,4.5,0.001),dinvgamma(seq(2,4.5,0.001)-params[3],params[1],params[2]),type="l",col="red")
```

It seems that I cannot attach the .csv file in here, but I can send it to anyone who is familiar and willing to help. I get the following error:

```
Error in optim(c(5, 2, 2), ll) : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

and I cannot understand why due to my lack of knowledge in R.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful because this code is an *ad hoc* implementation of a modified Inverse Gamma (for including a location parameter, see the comments in the answer for more details). Have a look at the answer [in this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31934/10525) for the implementation of the original Inverse Gamma.

Comment: Strange piece of code: dinvgamma(data-    par[3]

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Have a look at the comments of the OP in the referred question. The code passed through a couple of modifications. The idea is to produce a modified Inverse Gamma with support on $(par[3],\infty)$.

Comment: By the way perhaps the ML estimates for an inverse-Gamma can be computed with the distrMod R package ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent In the link I posted, the responder uses `fitdistr`.

Comment: This seems to be a question that is *only* about how to get R to do this. As such, it really should be on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) rather than here (although I understand why you put it here).

Comment: @gung The problem does not appear to be specific to `R`: it seems likely the OP would run into the same difficulty attempting this fit in the same way using any software (or even hand calculations). The issue seems to lie in the algorithm rather than the software platform.

Comment: @user, You're getting this message because your `ll` function returns `Inf` when the parameters are out of range.  Return a huge value like $10^{31}$ instead and you should be fine.  If not, there may be a genuine data analysis issue for us to pursue; but if so, we can just close this question.