# Maximum Likelihood Curve/Model Fitting in Python

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, python, curve-fitting, logistic-curve

I have some 2d data that I believe is best fit by a sigmoid function. I can do the fitting with the following python code snippet.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
ydata = array([0.1,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9, 0.9, 0.95])
xdata = array(range(0,len(ydata),1))

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
    y = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
    return y

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
```

However, I'd like to use a maximum likelihood approach so I can report likelihoods. I think it's possible do to this using the [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/) package, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Update:

I think the approach may be to redifine the likelihood function as it is described here:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_gmle.html

The plot of the above code snippet looks like this:

[image]

#### Update 2:

Here's how to do it in R:

```
require(bbmle)

# this sigmoid function is used to make some fake data
rsigmoid <- function(y1,y2,xi,xmid,w){
   y1+(y2-y1)/(1+exp((xmid-xi)/w))
}
counts <- round(rsigmoid(0, 1, 1:100+rnorm(100,0,3), 50, 10)*20,0)

# NOTE THAT THE SIGMOID FUNCTION IS REDEFINED AS AN R FORMULA
fit_sigmoid <- mle2(P1 ~ dbinom(prob=y1+(y2-y1)/(1+exp((xmid-xi)/w)), size=N), 
             start = list(xmid=50, w=10), 
             data=list(y1=0, y2=1, N=20, P1=counts, xi=1:100),
             method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(xmid=1,w=1e-5), upper=c(xmid=100,w=100))
```

Comment: This answer suggests a way I might do it (with some modifications) in R, but I'd like to keep everything in python if possible: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31934/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-inverse-gamma-distribution-in-r-or-rpy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode to do it. Of course, it depends on the error structure you choose. You don't need the stats models to do it, because Scipy has an minimizer built-in. The minimizer probably doesn't give you CIs though, like mle2 will. There may be another minimizer that will profile your parameters, but I don't know of one on the top of my head.

Anyway, here you go

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pylab as py

ydata = np.array([0.1,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9, 0.9, 0.95])
xdata = np.array(range(0,len(ydata),1))

def sigmoid(params):
    k = params[0]
    x0 = params[1]   
    sd = params[2]

    yPred = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)))

    # Calculate negative log likelihood
    LL = -np.sum( stats.norm.logpdf(ydata, loc=yPred, scale=sd ) )

    return(LL)


initParams = [1, 1, 1]

results = minimize(sigmoid, initParams, method='Nelder-Mead')
print results.x

estParms = results.x
yOut = yPred = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-estParms[0]*(xdata-estParms[1])))

py.clf()
py.plot(xdata,ydata, 'go')
py.plot(xdata, yOut)
py.show()
```

This gives me the following:
[image: MLfit]

Comment: This is close, but ideally I'd like to use a binomial not a normal distribution.

Comment: You can specify whatever family you want. Just change stats.norm.logpdf to stats.binom.logpmf and make the appropriate changes to your argument and that should do it.